# React Native send data on android [Type Error: Network request failed]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, axios, cloudinary

I'm trying to get pictures from the android image gallery and save them in my cloudinary account. I've used axios/fetch and got the error  "Network request failed". Below is my code:

```
_pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", result);
    formData.append("tags", 'text_detection');
    formData.append("upload_preset", "xxx");
    formData.append("api_key", "xxx");

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }

    return fetch("http://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/ebrugulec/image/upload", {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message)
    })
  }; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to upload with Cloudinary REST API but with no signature. 
You should sign the upload request and add the signature as part of the upload parameters.

How to generate signature:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#generating_authentication_signatures

Here is a code example:https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/issues/145#issuecomment-406852031

Instead, you can use Cloudniry SDK in order to easily upload the images.

--Yakir

Comment: Thank you so much your answer but I had handle it before with this post. https://medium.com/@ifeoluwaking24/how-to-upload-an-image-in-expo-react-native-to-firebase-using-cloudinary-24aac981c87